# Perl Catalyst - Obtaining JSON data from AJAX POST request

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, perl, catalyst

I am trying to obtain the JSON data that is sent to the server via an AJAX POST when a button is clicked on my `homescreen` page on my Catalyst application:

The AJAX POST that sends the JSON data to the server:

```
$("#saveCanvasStates").click(function () {
// button to save canvas states to a database

// Serialize the states array
var JsonStringForTransport = JSON.stringify({stateForUserNumber7: states});

// POST the JSON to the server
var thePost = $.ajax({
    url: 'homescreen',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JsonStringForTransport,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
});
```

I also have the following Catalyst Controller for the `homescreen` page which the button that sends the AJAX POST is located on:

**Catalyst Controller:**

```
package MyProject::Controller::Homescreen;

use strict;
use warnings;
use parent 'Catalyst::Controller';
use Data::Dumper;

__PACKAGE__->config->{namespace} = '';

sub homescreen :Path('/homescreen') :Args(0)  {

        my ( $self, $c ) = @_;

        $c->stash({title => 'Home Screen',
                   pagetype => 'html',
                   template => 'homescreen.html'
                 });


#here is where I think I need to obtain the JSON data from the AJAX POST request 
#and save it to my database

}

1;
```

Once I have this JSON data in a form I can work with I will then be saving it to a Postgres database.

From looking at the CPAN docs for [Catalyst::Request](http://search.cpan.org/~jjnapiork/Catalyst-Runtime-5.90051/lib/Catalyst/Request.pm#$req-%3Ebody_parameters), as it's my understanding this is what to refer to when dealing with request stuff, it's possible to use the following to do stuff with AJAX POST data?:

- $c->$req->body_data
- $c->$req->body_parameters
- $c->$req->body_params

But I am unsure about the best way to get the data into a form I can then insert into my database and which one of the methods should be used in preference?

I can find very little documentation that has helped me.

### Update (relating to RET's answer)

I definitely have `body_data` to display because when I do:

`print Dumper($c->req->body_data);`

I get the following printed in my development server log:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'stateForUserNumber7' => [
                                     {
                                       'width' => 102,
                                       'offsetY' => 56,
                                       'x' => 11,
                                       'height' => 102,
                                       'image' => {},
                                       'y' => 14,
                                       'contextIndex' => 2,
                                       'dragging' => bless( do{\(my $o = 0)}, 'Cpanel::JSON::XS::Boolean' ),
                                       'offsetX' => 73
                                     },
                                     {
                                       'width' => 102,
                                       'offsetY' => 34,
                                       'x' => 103,
                                       'height' => 102,
                                       'image' => {},
                                       'y' => 17,
                                       'contextIndex' => 3,
                                       'dragging' => $VAR1->{'stateForUserNumber7'}[0]{'dragging'},
                                       'offsetX' => 46
                                     }
                                   ]
        };
[info] *** Request 15 (1.250/s) [17427] [Fri Dec  6 00:02:22 2013] ***
[debug] Path is "homescreen"
[debug] "POST" request for "homescreen" from "192.168.1.100"
[debug] Rendering template "homescreen.html"
[debug] Response Code: 200; Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8; Content-Length: 7010
[info] Request took 0.025343s (39.459/s)
.------------------------------------------------------------+-----------.
| Action                                                     | Time      |
+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
| /homescreen                                                | 0.014044s |
| /end                                                       | 0.001992s |
|  -> Organiser::View::TT->process                           | 0.001058s |
'------------------------------------------------------------+-----------'
```

### Further update

This is the error it gives in the development server output when using `-d`:

```
Caught exception in Organiser::Controller::Homescreen->homescreen "Can't use an undefined value as a HASH reference at /home/fred/Organiser/script/../lib/Organiser/Controller/Homescreen.pm line 21."
```

This is the error I get from Stack Trace when running the development server:

```
Stack Trace
Package                             Line    File
Organiser::Controller::Homescreen   21    /home/fred/Organiser/lib/Organiser/Controller/Homescreen.pm

18: 
19: print STDERR Dumper $c->req->body_data; 
20: 
21: foreach my $data (@{$c->req->body_data->{stateForUserNumber7}}) {     <-- it highlights in bold this line
22:      print "DOLLAR DATA $data\n"; 
23: } 
24:

Organiser::Controller::Root     17  /home/fred/Organiser/lib/Organiser/Controller/Root.pm

14: sub index :Path :Args(0) { 
15: my ( $self, $c ) = @_; 
16: 
17: $c->forward('homescreen');       <-- it highlights in bold this line
18: 
19: } 
20:
```

Using Firebug this is the POST request that is occurring (after I comment out the foreach that is making it error)

```
Source
{"stateForUserNumber7":[{"dragging":false,"contextIndex":4,"image":{},"x":108,"y":4,"width":102,"height":102,"offsetX":45,"offsetY":65}]}
```

It is always `stateForUserNumber7` (I should have named it master_user or something really)

Comment: You can try to add to controller this string: 'print STDERR Dumper $c->req->params;'

Comment: `$c->req->body_data` ... "Returns a Perl representation of POST/PUT body data that is not classic HTML form data, such as JSON, XML, etc. **By default, Catalyst will parse incoming data of the type 'application/json' and return access to that data via this method**" -- so what does `$c->req->body_data` look like?

Comment: @mob - I did try `$c->req->body_data` as I saw the line in the docs that you showed above, but when using it I get an error `"Can't locate object method "body_data" via package "Catalyst::Request"...`? The other ones eg. `$c->$req->body_parameters` do not produce this error?

Comment: Then are you using the latest release of `Catalyst`? The `body_data` method is new since version 5.90049_003 (2013-09-20).

Comment: @mob - My version says `powered by Catalyst 5.90042`

Comment: Then either upgrade (so you can use `body_data`) or use `$c->req->body` and parse the JSON yourself.

Comment: @mob - Just upgraded to Catalyst 5.90051 and no more error with `$c->req->body_data` thanks. How do I then go about getting/printing the data that the `$c->req->body_data` method obtains? thanks for your help

Comment: Just humour me and try using `$c->req->params->{stateForUserNumber7}` instead of `body_data`. BTW your use of `$data` in line 22 is not going to print anything useful, just a HASH memory reference. Try printing `$data->{x}` or `Dumper($data)`

Comment: @RET - I used `req->params` instead of `body_data` in the foreach loop and it does not give the `undefined value as a HASH reference` any more and the app fires up correctly and is usable. But the foreach loop does not print anything to the debug screen (even when I use `$data->{x}` or `Dumper($data)` in it). It's as if its not actually getting into the foreach loop

Comment: I think you're just going to have to keep on poking around in the params hash. Have you tried changing line 19 to dump `$c->req->params` instead of `body_data`? Perhaps the structure is subtly different?

Comment: @RET - When using `print STDERR Dumper $c->req->params;` it does not dump anything... it just gives `$VAR1 = {};`?

Comment: Well, that's behaviour consistent with not having any parameters. Does your server log show that any were sent? Never mind, I've realized the problem. Am writing a new answer. Stand by...

Comment: See new answer. I've left the old one in place in case it's useful in its own right to anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*My other answer is (hopefully) useful information for anyone debugging Catalyst/JSON issues. But subsequent updates to the question have shown the problem here is actually something entirely different.*

There are not enough actions to support the required functionality here. If the `index` action forwards to the `homescreen` action which renders the `homescreen.html` template, then the `$.json()` call has to be to some other action which is responsible for handling the data save request **and nothing else**.

```
package MyProject::Controller::Homescreen;

use strict;
use warnings;
use parent 'Catalyst::Controller';
use JSON;

sub homescreen :Path('/homescreen') :Args(0)  {

    my ( $self, $c ) = @_;
    $c->stash({title => 'Home Screen',
               pagetype => 'html',
               template => 'homescreen.html'
    });
}

sub savecanvasstates :Local {
    my ($self, $c, @args) = @_;
    my $p = $c->req->param->{stateForUserNumber7} || die "wrong parameters!";
    my $result = {};
    foreach my $r (@{$p}) {
        # ... do something with $r->{x} etc
        $result->{output} = # construct whatever object the ajax caller expects
    }
    $c->res->body(to_json($result))
}

1;
```

And in some nearby JavaScript:

```
$("#saveCanvasStates").click(function () {
    // button to save canvas states to a database

    // Serialize the states array
    var JsonStringForTransport = JSON.stringify({stateForUserNumber7: states});

    // POST the JSON to the server
    var thePost = $.ajax({
        url: 'savecanvasstates',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JsonStringForTransport,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function(data, textStatus){ ... }
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){ ... }
    });
});
```

I hope all that makes what you have to do clearer.

Comment: I found this in Catalyst::Request on cpan: `$req->body_data - Catalyst will parse incoming data of the type 'application/json' and return access to that data via this method.` which may be the reason I get absolutely nothing when I use `print STDERR Dumper $c->req->params;` but do when I use `print STDERR Dumper $c->req->body_data;`?  I take this to mean application/json is automatically only handled by `body_data`?

Comment: If what you've written in your original post is an accurate reflection of your software, there's a fundamental issue in the design. You cannot support an AJAX call and a default template rendering within the same action without doing something seriously weird.

Comment: The latest and greatest version of Catalyst may indeed read and return JSON automagically, but that doesn't fix the issue with the code you've provided. It would only simplify the `savecanvasstates` action to a degree.

Comment: I tried your new answer... it dosn't seem to ever get into the `savecanvasstates` sub. Ive added some print statements `print STDERR "HELLO\n";` to the sub/action but they never get printed on the debug output of the development server?. thanks a lot

Comment: Figured out the above problem - I specified the explicit path `sub savecanvasstates :Path('/homescreen') :Args(0)  {` instead of `:Local` and it now gets inside the sub/action.

Comment: Glad to hear it - the exact URI architecture wasn't clear enough from the OP to know exactly whether that should be a :Local, :Path or some other action type. Please tick and/or upvote answer(s) that solved your problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42898/discussion-between-perl-user-and-ret)

Answer (score 4):

Although the built in logging stuff is great when you are making logs to persist and to do analysts on, I find it not terribly using for basic debugging.  I've lately been using Devel::Dwarn which is an easy install.  This is like a warn dumper + rolled up very neatly.

If you start your app like so

```
perl -MDevel::Dwarn ...
```

You can stick `Dwarn $ref` and get a nice stderr output:

```
Dwarn $c->req->body_data
```

Should give you a neat review.  Plus if you drop the `-MDevel::Dwarn` you'll get errors in all the places you accidentally left `Dwarn` out (something I should have done with the borked release of Runner 002 last month).

If that is confusing to you just try:

(after `cpanm Devel::Dwarn`)

```
use Devel::Dwarn;
Dwarn $c->req->body_data
```

You should get a deep structure output to your console. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Your Catalyst app won't receive JSON. The `dataType` argument tells `$.ajax()` how to *parse* the data returned from the server. What's sent to the server is a bog-standard GET or POST request with HTML form parameters.

By the time Catalyst receives them, they're plain old keys inside `$c->req->params`, perfectly suitable for whatever database actions you want to whip up.

So if

```
/* JS */
JsonStringForTransport = { foo: "bar", baz: "quux" };
```

then at the Catalyst end, you'll receive:

```
# perl
my $foo = $c->req->params->{foo}; # or $c->req->body_params->{foo}
if ($c->req->params->{baz} eq "quux"){ ... }
```

... and so on.

---

**UPDATE**

So `body_data` contains a hash (unsurprisingly), which has a key `stateForUserNumber7` that contains a reference to an array of hashes. That's what that Dumper output is telling you.

You should be able to access `body_data` using the following:

```
my $first_x = $c->req->body_data->{stateForUserNumber7}->[0]->{x};
print STDERR "first_x = $first_x\n"; # should print first_x = 11
```

However, it's more likely you'll want to do something like:

```
foreach my $data (@{$c->req->body_data->{stateForUserNumber7}}) {
    # do something with $data->{x}, $data->{y}, $data->{height} etc
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

*jnap* has published a very good article on how to use `body_data` in the [2013 Catalyst Advent Calendar](http://catalyst.perl.org/calendar/2013/6). If you are using this feature in your app instead of the more traditional `params`, you should definitely take the time to read and absorb it.

---

**UPDATE**

Sorry, misspoke earlier regarding `dataType`, so I've corrected that. But it doesn't change the fundamentals of my answer.

I think you're going to have to introspect your `body_data` to figure out what's going wrong. Is it always 'stateForUserNumber7', or does that vary from request to request? What does

```
$c->log->debug("body_params keys: " _ join(", ", keys %{ $c->req->body_data }));
```

produce?

You have to use the development server (i.e. `bin/myapp_server.pl`) so that you get the full debug output to assist you. Debugging via Apache or FastCGI is not recommended at all.

Comment: Excellent, your explanation at the top was very useful thanks. What is the correct way to print certain elements or loop through and print all elements from the `$c->req->body_data` data structure. Thanks for your help

Comment: If you just want to dump them out to inspect them, use `$c->log->debug("body_data: " . Dumper($c->req->body_data));`. But the GET and POST parameters should be visible in your server log - there's a table of them in the output for every request cycle.

Comment: What if I wanted to store a particular element of the `body_data` data structure in a variable or store/print a particular branch of the `body_data` data structure. How do I iterate through the elements in this data structure? thanks for your help.

Comment: It is just a data structure. Have a look and see what `keys %{$c->req->body_data}` returns. It should be just like the foo and baz examples in my answer.

Comment: When I do the following: `foreach my $var1 (keys %{$c->req->body_data}) { print "$var1\n"; }` I keep getting a `Can't use an undefined value as a HASH reference at...` error. What am I doing wrong here. I get the same error when I try and do `print keys %{$c->req->body_data};`. Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you sure you have `body_data` to display? What output are you getting in your development server log? BTW, you should definitely not use `print` (defaulting to `STDOUT`) in Catalyst, it plays havoc with what gets returned to the client. `print STDERR` is fine.

Comment: Yes I definitely think I have `body_data`, please see the update to my question. Thanks for the `print STDERR` tip as well :)

Comment: Thanks for the Advent Calendar update, I shall definitely have a look. Also when I use the method you suggested in your update to access the body_data I still get the following error `Caught exception in Organiser::Controller::Homescreen->homescreen "Can't use an undefined value as a HASH reference at...`. I cant see why it is not working though? thanks for your help

Comment: I've updated my answer again. You might also want to have a look at the Developer Tools in your browser, and investigate what the browser is sending to your server with each request. That could illuminate things a bit.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my question again to give some more error details. Also I get a `Bareword found error` when using `$c->log->debug("body_params keys: " _ join(", ", keys %{ $c->req->body_data }));`, thanks very much for your help.